# How to make pandas.to_sql and django work?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am following the docs but getting an error when using the `if_exists: replace` parameter. DB table is already created (did so with django's syncdb command). The docs on `pandas.to_sql()` says:

```
if_exists: {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’
    replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
```

which throws the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydata' doesn't exist")
```

oddly enough, when I run the code once again, it works and data gets inserted correctly. But then again, I always need to run the code twice.

As for the error message, the table does exist in the first place but what I noticed pandas is dropping it and then recreating it, inserting data when the code is run for the second time.

Any guess?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? There was a bug with if_exists (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4110) which was fixed only in 0.13.1. BTW, at the moment the sql module is getting a big rewrite based on sqlalchemy, which will be released in pandas 0.14 (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22464712/653364)

Comment: I need to upgrade, thanks!